# django-if template doesnt work properly

Tags: python, django

I have a list of stations and I have to display stations from 'start'. start and stop contain station ids. I am trying in this way but when I run all I get is a blank page.
showtrain.html :-

```
 <table>
 <tr>
  {% for st in st_list %}
    {% if  st.station_id >= start %}
    <td> {{ st.station_id }} </td>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
```

nothing works inside if except conditions like {% if start %}. i know i am missing something trivial. Please help me figure it out. i am using django 1.6.
edit: views.py-

```
def runtrain(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #request.post.get method retrieves user input from a form
            start = request.POST.get('start', None)
        stop = request.POST.get('stop', None)
        rid = request.session.get('route_id')
        stlist = SequenceTable.objects.filter(route_id = rid)
        #print start
        data2 = {
                "start" : start,
                "stop" : stop,
                "st_list" : stlist,

            }
    return render(request,"showtrain.html",data2)
```

models.py-

```
 class SequenceTable(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField( primary_key=True )
        route_id = models.ForeignKey( route, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        station_id = models.ForeignKey(Stations, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        sequence_no = models.IntegerField( null=True )

        #def __str__(self):
        #   return self.sequence_no
class Stations(models.Model):
    station_id = models.AutoField( primary_key=True )
    station = models.CharField( max_length=20 )
    station_code = models.CharField( max_length=10 )
  def __str__(self):
        return self.station_code
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the elements of `st_list`, to make sure you're returning the data properly?

Comment: #rofls yes, all entries of st_list are printed when i completely remove the if template

Comment: firstly do your `for` and `if` logic in views and debug using print statement and check all values in terminal using print.

Comment: #mahendra kamble, surprisingly if doesnt work even in view. i printed start, stlist.station_id from views, output is like : 134(start), (ids): 133,
134,
135
station_id and start match at 134 but still it doesnt enter if statement. i have no clue why

Comment: We don't have enough information to answer your question. The code looks fine so the problem can be in your data... we don't have the data you are using to execute the view and hence cannot tell whether the actual output matches your expectation or not. Also: instead of saying "it returns an empty page" you could post the actual source code produced, which should definitely contain *something* even though nothing that is rendered.

Comment: Start is a string, and station_id is an int. pass `"start": int(start)` instead.

Comment: #RemcoGerlich thank you so much, it worked! now i know what i have been doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

as stated by  RemcoGerlich the problem lies in mismatched datatype. the value of start returned from form is string type and station_id is integer. if cannot compare them and hence control doesnt enter if statements so nothing gets printed